# SDK QML slider on release signal

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml, sdk

I am using the slider component from the 15.04 Ubuntu SDK components, [see here for the docs](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-15.04/Ubuntu.Components.Slider/). Currently, there is no signal for releasing the slider handle, but there is one for when it is *touched* (when there is a click on the slider). I was wondering if there is a way to implement this, perhaps using the boolean variable *pressed*, which tells us: *Whether the Slider is currently being pressed*?

Answer (score 2):

QML properties come with signals that fire when that property changes.  A property `foo` has the corresponding signal `onFooChanged`.  This suggests two ways you could notice when the slider is released:

1) Connect to the `onPressedChanged` signal.  This will be fired both on press and on release, so you'll need to check that the value of `pressed` is `false` before running the code that you want to run on release.

2) Connect to the `onValueChanged` signal.  Assuming you have `live` set to `false`, this will fire only when the slider is released **at a new value**.  Depending on your needs, this may or may not be desired.